# Changing names of android styles but app crashes

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, app-themes

my files:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml (part):

```
<activity android:name=".actionbar.ActionBarSlider"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.*****.testapp.Home" />
    </activity>
```

After i change

`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">` to `<style name="ActionBarSlider" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">`

and

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` to `android:theme="@style/ActionBarSlider"`

the app crashes on Launch.
What is my mistake?

Comment: can you provide your logcat? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried to Clean your project afterward?  Sometimes mucking with the XML causes R to go out of sync..

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla adm: http://puu.sh/kASIX/11e83c4c01.png

Comment: @durbnpoisn what do you mean with clean?

Comment: @SeseSchneider put the logcat in your question... not a print screen.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla logcat: http://pastebin.com/xgHrCYux

Comment: @Sese:  In Eclipse, there is an option to "clean" your project.  This will force the IDE to go through and refresh/regenerate all the misc. files that are used when you compile.  All the files that you are not supposed to edit by hand because they are generated.

Comment: @durbnpoisn clean (rebuild in AndroidStudio) with no succes

Comment: @SeseSchneider do you know how to read the logcat? you just need a few lines... not the all thing. When it crash, there you need to check the exception.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla for sure i know, but you asked for the entire logcat, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 10-06 22:00:33.730 717-731/? W/WindowManager:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #31: You must supply
>   a layout_height attribute.

In your main activitys layout resource file (*in line 31*) you got a `LinearLayout` element which doesn't have a `android:layout_height=""` attribute.

Comment: i dont think so: http://pastebin.com/nucQJ45C

I also tried to change `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` to `match_parent` with no succes

Comment: than maybe in one of your Fragments inside the ViewPager?

Comment: @zkminusck He doesn't try to open any dialog! ;)

Comment: @IchordeDionysos okay, my mistake :) Sese Schneider did you also tried to close and reopen the IDE after the clean and rebuild?